# vue-router: how to check if current route is a route or one of its subroutes?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm wrapping router-link to add some features.

I need to check if current route is a route or a subdolder of a route.

*Something like the following*

> I know it cannot works, because :active need a boolean, but javascript String.match returns an array;: it's to explain my goal

```
:active="$route.name.match('customer_users*')"
```

In my router.js I definied that `/customer/{customer_id}/users` is named `customer_users` and that  `/customer/{customer_id}/users/{user_id}` is named `customer_users_edit`.

So i'd like to be able to set ":active" in my wrapper for both these routes.

Comment: Can't you just write a boolean expression there? Something like `$route.name.match('customer_users*').length()>0`

Comment: Yes and no, because I'll need to also check if match is null before check its length

Comment: FYI, the regex method you're looking for is `RegExp.prototype.test()`, eg `/^customer_users.*/.test($route.name)` but there are better ways to do this

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use the `$route.matched` property to see if the current route is your `customer_users` or any of its children.

For example, using [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```html
:active="$route.matched.some(({ name }) => name === 'customer_users')"
```

See https://v3.router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties

> **$route.matched**
>
> type: `Array<RouteRecord>`
>
> An Array containing **route records** for all nested path segments of the current route.

Answer (score 0):

I like the following for matching multiple routes:

```
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

if(route.matched.some(({ path }) => path.startsWith('/redirect'))){
    //handle redirect
}
```

You are checking if the current path